# How do I remove all objects in a List<string> on Windows Phone 7 Silverlight C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do I remove all objects in a List on Windows Phone 7 Silverlight C# (latest SDK)?

The method `myList.RemoveAll()` does not exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
myList.Clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three ways to do this,

- `myList.Clear();`
- `myList = null;`
- `myList = new List<yourType>();`

Answer (score 0):

Proper Clearing of a List Box

listName.Items.Clear();
listName.SelectedItem = null;